# Renaming wp-content folder dynamically

Tags: php, security, wp-config

Is it possible to rename the wp-content folder dynamically? I am building a custom framework to use on themes and it would be nice to set it up where it does everything on its own.

I am using this following code right now in wp-config

```
define ('WP_CONTENT_DIR','/name_of_new_folder');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL','http://example.com/name_of_new_folder');
```

Can I pull the site domain through dynamically with PHP?

Answer (score 2):

### Don't do what seems to be possible...

You *can* use the possibility to change the WordPress constants `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and `WP_CONTENT_URL` in your `wp-config.php`.

> **BUT** it really, really, really, really is **not** recommended.

### Why? not recommended??

It's pretty easy: Just do a cross file search (with your IDE or for e.g. Notepad++) for `wp-content` and you'll find it hardcoded it many places. Some of the stuff will still work, but some wont. *Yeah, I've already tried that.*

Comment: I've read a bunch about it and it seemed the only problem people had was with plugins not working correctly? I believe this is due to bad plugin writing. Is there anything else I should look out for? I'm doing this solely for security reasons.

Comment: @ftntravis That's security through obscurity, so no _real_ security. Actually there's no real reason to change the name. Aside from poorly coded plugins (the majority), there're things that rely on it. For example other constants like `PLUGINDIR` or `MUPLUGINDIR` (both deprecated, but in enough plugins still in use). Then there're points where you'll maybe hit edge cases in core. The MU blogs dir for example. My advice: Just don't do it. It doesn't add any value or security. It just _looks different_, nothing else.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I appreciate it! And will definitely take it into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . 'name_of_new_folder');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/name_of_new_folder');
```

Comment: Check if your target directory [`is_writable()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php) first. Usually it isn’t.